# How to use lm-sensors?

Tags: sensors

I wanted to install a package to monitor the temperature of my CPU called [lm-sensors](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lm-sensors/)[image: Install lm-sensors].

According to Synaptic, it's already installed.

Can someone give me some simple step-by-step instructions on how I can actually run it from the command line or otherwise?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Once `lm-sensors` is installed you need to reach for your terminal:

type

```
sudo sensors-detect
```

just press ENTER for everything it suggests (shown in Uppercase)

At the end it will ask you whether to add what it finds to `/etc/modules`.  If you are happy with the findings type "yes".

More information about lm-sensors and how to tailor it for your system can be found on the lm-sensors [installation wiki page](http://www.lm-sensors.org/wiki/FAQ/Chapter2)

Typing

```
sensors
```

will display the values for the sensors detected previously.

e.g.

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:       +55.0°C  (crit = +90.0°C)
```

Comment: +1 for `sensors-detect`, I got two extra sensors from it :)

Comment: Tip: use the `watch` command to see updates of the output of the `sensors` command in real time! Like so: `$ watch sensors`

Comment: Do NOT use `sensors-detect`! It can permanently damage your hardware! http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTQ3MDE

Comment: @JopV. - you need to read the article more carefully - the developers asked distro packagers to backport the stable version.  That is what ubuntu did.  http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/lm-sensors/lm-sensors_3.3.4-2ubuntu1/changelog

Comment: I had to run sudo service kmod restart to see the results after sensors-detect

Comment: `$ watch -d -n1 sensors` is a really nice way to monitor whats happening.

Answer (score 32):

### [lm-sensors](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lm-sensors) [image: Install lm-sensors]

is a set of tools to control and view sensors that may be present on your hardware. Included are several applications that run from the command line:

- [sensors](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/sensors.1.html): shows the current readings of all sensor chips.
- [sensord](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/sensord.8.html): daemon to periodically log sensor readings to syslog
- [fancontrol](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/fancontrol.8.html): calculates fan speeds from temperatures and sets the corresponding PWM outputs
- [pwmconfig](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/pwmconfig.8.html): tests the PWM outputs of sensors and configures fancontrol
- and more (see [lm-sensors documentation](http://www.lm-sensors.org/wiki/Documentation) for details)

To run these programs open a terminal and type the name of the application (including optional parameters, see manpages for details). This will give an output similar as shown here for **sensors**:

```
~$ sensors

k8temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Core0 Temp:  +30.0°C                                    
Core0 Temp:  +30.0°C                                    
Core1 Temp:  +29.0°C                                    
Core1 Temp:  +36.0°C                                    

it8718-isa-0228
Adapter: ISA adapter
[...] # shortened
```

Configuration of lm-sensors is done by configuration files in `/etc/sensors3.conf` and in `/etc/sensors.conf` (for details see [manpage for sensors.conf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/sensors.conf.5.html)).

Comment: +1 for introducing me to commands I didn't know about (fancontrol, pwmconfig)

Comment: @jwernerny: there are even more :)

Comment: Thanks. But I don't see `sensord` on Ubuntu bionic 18.04. Is there a different way to log readings?

Answer (score 20):

### [psensor](http://packages.ubuntu.com/psensor)

```
sudo apt install psensor
```

I'm quite fond of `psensor`... it runs on the Indicator Bar (the "Systray" near the clock), so it is perhaps the most unobtrusive app that uses `lm-sensors`. It also can show a nice window with graphs displaying the history of each sensor, just like System Monitor does for memory, CPU usage, etc. It has logging too!

It also uses sensors other than `lm-sensors`, like `hddtemp` for HDD temperatures and NVidia and AMD GPU (video cards) temperature and fan.

[image: screenshot of psensor]

Better screenshots than mine can be found in the author's website:

http://wpitchoune.net/psensor/

Answer (score 14):

### [xsensors](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xsensors) [image: Install xsensors]

```
sudo apt install xsensors
```

It has a graphical interface that is easy to understand. It shows me the motherboard voltages (there are four of them), the CPU and motherboard temperature as well as the CPU fan speed, the speed of three chassis fans and the power fan speed. All monitored in real time. And it loads into the the Unity Dash.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use XFCE, I think it`s better to show it in toolbar, like this,  use this plugin:

[image]

The effect is this:

[image]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ide37.png):

Answer (score 1):

For the record, if anyone is interested to get e-mail notifications/alerts on fans dying or temperatures shooting through the roof, I've written a simple service in Perl to do that monitoring for me. [I've uploaded the source code and README to Github.](https://github.com/xrysf03/sensormon) I.e. yet another e-mail notification daemon :-)
Couldn't find anything similarly trivial in the interwebs, now that sensord is deprecated... = just my two cents worth.