# How do I install lmsensors on a server?

Tags: installation, server, apt

I am trying to install `lm-sensors` on ubuntu server 11.04 with the following command 
`sudo apt-get install lm-sensors`, but I am getting the following error:

> Error Package lm-sensors has no installation candidate.

I need a program that can show me detailed statistics about temperatures and usage of my components (cpu, ram, hdd) like `lm-sensors`.

If I cannot install it, exist other option like lm-sensors ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to enable the *Universe* repository to install the package.

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

remove the *#* from the beginning of the lines that look something like:

```
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty universe
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty universe
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates universe
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates universe
```

Save and then refresh your repository information:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

To install the package:

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors
```

---

Linked Question:

1. [How to use lm-sensors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53762/how-to-use-to-use-lm-sensors/53782#53782)

Comment: The apt manager works, but i get an error saying that fan controller is in conflict and it cannot install it. I installed fan controller a time ago, and now i need to remove it in order to install lm sensors. Please tell me the command to remove fan, is crucial for me to install lm sensors to see the cpu temperatures.

Comment: ok - edit your question with the output that you see - normally with a "conflict" message you just run a "sudo apt-get purge [package name]" type statement to remove the conflicting package.

Comment: sudo apt-get update, and then sudo apt-get install lm-sensors and works, thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

The error shows you may have spelled it wrong. Try the following command

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors
```