# proliant dl380 g4 lm_sensors doesn't work

Tags: server, temperature

I have ubuntu server 11.04 edition, and i have installed and configured lm-sensors properly and grub boot is normal/default set. When i type the following command:

```
sensors
```

i get:

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +8.3Â°C  (crit = +31.3Â°C)

and after:

```
  sudo sensors-detect
```

Output is: Sorry, no sensors were detected. Either your system has no sensors, or they are not supported, or they are connected to an I2C or SMBus adapter that is not supported. If you find out what chips are on your board, check lm-sensors.org/wiki/Devices for driver status.

This can't be a right output, anybody had this kind of problem on this server?
I need a bios upgrade? If so please provide me with a detailed guide because bios is a delicate thing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you run `sensors-detect`?

Comment: correct - as per http://askubuntu.com/questions/53762/how-to-use-to-use-lm-sensors/53782#53782

Comment: That's a little strange  - what model dl380 are you using?  Are you using any grub boot options - for example acpi=off?  You could be correct - a bios update may be required.  Remember - as this is a question and answer site, please add any relevant information back into your question - stuff tends to get lost/missed in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it seems the HP Proliant DL servers do not use the SMBus for the sensors that is why they are not detected, a bios update will not fix the issue either.

HP has a utility to read data from the Internal Lights Out Management board and the hplog utility is used to get the temp and fan speed values.

I found some correspondence confirming this [here](http://lists.lm-sensors.org/pipermail/lm-sensors/2006-December/018489.html)  this dates back to 2006 so it is likely HP have not done anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

This might be pretty late, but you can get HP-Tools for your Proliant:

```
wget http://mirror.safehostnet.com/debian-hp/pool/non-free/hp-health_8.7.0.1.2-5_amd64.deb

dpkg -i hp-health_8.7.0.1.2-5_amd64.deb   

hpasmcli -s "show temp"
```

It works like a charm:

```
root@server:/tmp# hpasmcli -s "show temp"

Sensor   Location              Temp       Threshold
------   --------              ----       ---------
#1        PROCESSOR_ZONE       17C/62F    62C/143F 
#2        CPU#1                18C/64F    80C/176F 
#3        I/O_ZONE             18C/64F    60C/140F 
#4        CPU#2                 -          -       
#5        POWER_SUPPLY_BAY     13C/55F    53C/127F
```