# How can I see the GPU temperture of my ATI graphics card?

Tags: ati, fan

I trying to work out how long can my graphics card last with its fan off without overheating.

when I'm browsing the Internet, the graphics card fan is the loudest thing in my computer.

So my question is, how do I monitor the GPU temperature of my ATI Radeon HD 4850 graphics card.

Comment: it has to do with ubuntu or linux because i want to find a program compatible with it that will allow me to see my gpu tempurature

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are using the proprietary driver (fglrx), then the command you want is `aticonfig --odgt`.

So far as I'm aware, for many cards this sensor will not be exposed through lm-sensors.

Comment: and `aticonfig --odgc` for GPU load (current usage %), along with clock speeds

Comment: Can you also try Psensor

Answer (score 5):

Not long until it fries. Depending on the amount of graphic workload you're doing, manufacturing process, accumulated dust could be minutes, hours. buy an aftermarket fanless cooling replacement if  noise is a problem.

To monitor your GPU Temperature, use this Q&A to help find the GPU sensor:

[How to use lm-sensors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53762/how-to-use-to-use-lm-sensors)

Comment: I just cleaned my graphics card from dust today, and no there will be almost no load on it, since all ill be using is like firefox. Im asking how long will it last without causing ANY damage at all?

Comment: Of course it will cause damage, heat causes damage to all electronics under extended periods of time, the card can get to ~120°C and it's supposed to shut off or it will fry. I'm certain no one has ever tried to just burn a card just to see how long does it takes too happen..

Comment: but would it last 20 seconds?

Comment: I'd guess it can hold up 20 secs, you can install `lm-sensors` to monitor the temp so you don't get past the threshold.

Comment: Whats lm-sensors, is it ubuntu 12.4 compatible?

Comment: Search it in the Software Center.

Comment: it doesn't show my graphics card fan or temperature even thpught i got the drivers installed

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/53762/how-to-use-to-use-lm-sensors

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, (See http://www.unixmen.com/howto-install-ati-display-driver-in-ubuntu/ to install) then type

```
sudo aticonfig --initial
```

Then

```
aticonfig --odgt
```

OUT:

```
Default Adapter - ATI Radeon HD 5700 Series
                  Sensor 0: Temperature - 45.00 C
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors
sensors
```

Which outputs something like:

```
radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:   +48.5°C  (crit = +120.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this using bash script which sets fan speed to actual temp. I mean if chip temp is 60deg fan speed id 60%. Then I run this under root cron every minute. I created `/bin/atiSpeedCron` file with this content:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
read temp < <(/usr/bin/aticonfig --od-gettemperature | grep "Sensor 0" | cut -c43-47)
echo temp: $temp
aticonfig --pplib-cmd "set fanspeed 0 $temp"
```

then I updated cron using

```
crontab -e
```

under root account I entered this line:

```
* * * * * /bin/atiSpeedCron
```

this made me forget about ati fans. btw/ I think grivers should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Since proprietary drivers are not supported anymore, I chose hardware solution. I took ventilator with standard power connector for atx case and taped it over the card. Suppose it's not good for gaming and cryptomining but works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do `modprobe it87` and if you are lucky, lm-sensors will give you the info.

If the card runs really hot, you can try to reduce its performance (if the drm module allows that):

```
echo low > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the HD 4xxx series does not have particularly good power saving features in the Open Source driver today, let alone when this question was written.

Unless the card was designed to run with the fan off, it will not be able to run at all without it.  Additionally, most AMD cards contain firmware that regulates the fan.  I would not recommend forcing off the fan, but instead simply relying on the card's internal firmware to regulate the fan speed.

To reduce the fan speed, you would need to simply reduce heat production.  I would recommend reading up on the latest power save options to force the card to remain at minimal clock speed.  This will give you decreased heat production at the cost of decreased performance.