# Is my CPU-Temperature OK?

Tags: cpu, temperature

I just brought my Laptop to a Service-Center to get it cleaned.
Now under normal use (using apt-get, watching videos, web-browsing...) my cpu-temp is between 55-70°C. 
If I put it under Stress with 4xburnP6 it goes up to 90-95°C after 5-10 Minutes and seems to stay there.
(Idle Temperature is about 44-48°C)

So I'm curios, can this Temperatures considered as normal or save?

(BTW I'm using a Thinkpad T420s with cooling-pad)

Comment: The maximum temperature allowed at the processor die is 100 C.  See [Here](http://ark.intel.com/products/52229/Intel-Core-i5-2520M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_20-GHz).

Comment: A question of interest: http://askubuntu.com/questions/53762/how-to-use-to-use-lm-sensors

Answer (score 0):

95° C is normally the temperature at which the system will initate an emergency shutdown, so no, it is not normal.  It sounds like the service center broke something.

Comment: No they didn't broke something, they only didn't fix it ;-)
What would be the normal CPU-Temperature for a Notebook which runs at 100% CPU Load for 1 Hour?

Comment: http://www.notebookcheck.com/Test-Lenovo-Thinkpad-T520-Notebook.51213.0.html this article says that a CPU-Temp of 86°C under Load for several Hours is fine...so everything under 90°C is OK for 100% CPU Load?

Comment: @sine, anything under 90 is ok, yes... the lower the better of course.

Comment: Ok just tweaked my Thinkfan config if I set Fan-Level to 7 if it hits 78°C than the CPU will stay at 80-85°C at least for the last 10 Minutes or so. But under normal use I will never ever have 100% CPU Load for so long. Maybe if I have to compile something but I don't use Gentoo so that will be rare ;-)

Comment: and after I killed all burnP6 Processes the CPU goes down to 45°C in 1-2 Minutes. So I think it should be fine right?