# How to read hardware temperatures and other info in Ubuntu

Tags: temperature

So all the previous answers that I have found pretty much tell me to install lm-sensors. But there is a lot of configuration with it that I find odd. I am sure there are more simpler ways.

For instance I can do cat `cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone2/temp` and it will print out a temperature. So I guess the `thermal-zones` in that `thermal` folder are related to various hardware parts in my computer? But is there any documentation about this? Like how to read them exactly and what devices each zone points to.

Or maybe there is even a better way of doing this?

Comment: check this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto

Comment: I explicitly stated that I would like to find a solution not involving the use of lm-sensors.

Comment: http://www.noobslab.com/2014/08/useful-panel-indicators-collection-for.html

 check 20,21,22 and 23 indicator in the posted link

Comment: See this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/262777/32239) about psensors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try acpi.

```
sudo apt-get install acpi
```

Then run:

```
 acpi -V
```

Here are the more options for acpitool:

[Ubuntu manpage for acpitool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/acpitool.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

After installing **lm-sensors** you can install, for example, GKrellM.

```
sudo apt-get install gkrellm
```

**GKrellM** is at the right side of [the image](http://postimg.org/image/thmqccsjv/) where it is using invisible skin (downloaded from http://www.larsen-b.com/Article/284.html) in my Ubuntu 14.10. At GKrellM Configuration Panel (Sensors), you can enable each one of temperature sensors that have been founded by **lm-sensors**.