# Using the sensor command doesn't give me fan speed in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, fan, temperature, lm-sensors

I'm trying to detect my fan speeds.

I've installed `lm-sensors` but when I run `sensors` I get this:

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +63.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:         +63.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:         +63.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

I'm a bit confuse as why is this because I had Elementary OS freya installed and `sensors` gave me the fan speed.

How can I fix this on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

**EDIT**

Here's the log after running `sudo sensors-detect`

http://paste.ubuntu.com/15955853/

Comment: Did you [configure sensors](http://askubuntu.com/questions/53762/how-to-use-lm-sensors) with `sudo sensors-detect`?

Comment: @Takkat I ran the command, and answered everything yes as I've no idea what it's doing, it added `coretemp` to the `/etc/modules` and I restarted my pc but still no luck.

Comment: Looks like your current system configurations doesn't allow reading the fan speed on Linux. A newer kernel and `lm-sensors` version may change that, so you could try the live DVD/USB of Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I am puzzled. Your sensors output says you have a Dell Inspiron 3521 laptop. According to the Dell website this has the Intel HM77 chipset. According to the Intel chipset datasheet this chipset only has fan speed monitoring and PWM controls in the workstation and server models and you have the mobile model.

Comment: @SteveRoome what does this means? This Dell Inspiron is weird, as it came with 6gb of ram instead of 4 as they sell it.

Comment: It means I cant see how you could have monitored or controlled the fan speed in the past as it doesnt look like your laptop has the necessary hardware.