Random shutdowns - What's going on?
Not much more to say really. Computer keeps saying it's going to shutdown in 60 seconds. Super annoying. I think it happens once or more a day. I've been through the settings and can't see it scheduled anywhere.
confusion@nuc:~$ sudo journalctl -b -1 -e
[sudo] password for confusion: 
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-c1d31fbf\x2d58ab\x2d4bed\x2daae2\x2dfaecc78edb02.service: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Stopped File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/c1d31fbf-58ab-4bed-aae2-faecc78edb02.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Removed slice Slice /system/systemd-fsck.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Stopped target Preparation for Local File Systems.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Stopping Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling...
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: systemd-sysusers.service: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Stopped Create System Users.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: systemd-remount-fs.service: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2did-dm\x2duuid\x2dLVM\x2dxhbgSLCYhhDBlZY1VmaQPNxD2biTDqmbMgygNLOYKem7jkU9f6EKe3IAnoB8KDnD.swap: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-LVM-xhbgSLCYhhDBlZY1VmaQPNxD2biTDqmbMgygNLOYKem7jkU9f6EKe3IAnoB8KDnD.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2did-dm\x2dname\x2dvgubuntu\x2dswap_1.swap: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-vgubuntu-swap_1.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-d0cfc507\x2d33d3\x2d44c8\x2d8e90\x2d676b04b1f8c0.swap: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/d0cfc507-33d3-44c8-8e90-676b04b1f8c0.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: dev-vgubuntu-swap_1.swap: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/vgubuntu/swap_1.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: dev-dm\x2d2.swap: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/dm-2.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: dev-mapper-vgubuntu\x2dswap_1.swap: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc lvm[68182]:   2 logical volume(s) in volume group "vgubuntu" unmonitored
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: lvm2-monitor.service: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Stopped Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Reached target System Shutdown.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Reached target Late Shutdown Services.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: systemd-poweroff.service: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Finished System Power Off.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Reached target System Power Off.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Shutting down.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd-journald[499]: Journal stopped
...skipping...
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-c1d31fbf\x2d58ab\x2d4bed\x2daae2\x2dfaecc78edb02.service: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Stopped File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/c1d31fbf-58ab-4bed-aae2-faecc78edb02.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Removed slice Slice /system/systemd-fsck.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Stopped target Preparation for Local File Systems.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Stopping Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling...
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: systemd-sysusers.service: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Stopped Create System Users.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: systemd-remount-fs.service: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2did-dm\x2duuid\x2dLVM\x2dxhbgSLCYhhDBlZY1VmaQPNxD2biTDqmbMgygNLOYKem7jkU9f6EKe3IAnoB8KDnD.swap: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-LVM-xhbgSLCYhhDBlZY1VmaQPNxD2biTDqmbMgygNLOYKem7jkU9f6EKe3IAnoB8KDnD.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2did-dm\x2dname\x2dvgubuntu\x2dswap_1.swap: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-vgubuntu-swap_1.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-d0cfc507\x2d33d3\x2d44c8\x2d8e90\x2d676b04b1f8c0.swap: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/d0cfc507-33d3-44c8-8e90-676b04b1f8c0.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: dev-vgubuntu-swap_1.swap: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/vgubuntu/swap_1.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: dev-dm\x2d2.swap: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/dm-2.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: dev-mapper-vgubuntu\x2dswap_1.swap: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc lvm[68182]:   2 logical volume(s) in volume group "vgubuntu" unmonitored
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: lvm2-monitor.service: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Stopped Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Reached target System Shutdown.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Reached target Late Shutdown Services.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: systemd-poweroff.service: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Finished System Power Off.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Reached target System Power Off.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd[1]: Shutting down.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
Apr 05 01:47:11 nuc systemd-journald[499]: Journal stopped
lines 965-1000/1000 (END)

Output of sudo crontab -l and crontab -l:
confusion@nuc:~$ sudo crontab -l
[sudo] password for confusion:
no crontab for root
confusion@nuc:~$ crontab -l
no crontab for confusion

Output of sudo systemctl --reverse list-dependencies poweroff.target
poweroff.target

Output of systemctl --reverse list-dependencies shutdown.target
shutdown.target

lm-sensors temperature date
confusion@nuc:~$ sensors
iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:            N/A  

nvme-pci-3c00
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +46.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +76.8°C)
                       (crit = +78.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +46.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +46.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +73.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +69.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +73.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

pch_skylake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +70.0°C


What does root's crontab look like?

confusion@nuc:~$ sudo crontab -l     [sudo] password for confusion:      no crontab for root     confusion@nuc:~$ crontab -l     no crontab for confusion     confusion@nuc:~$    i give up trying to format

Please add the information we ask for in your question (including the above comment). Also add system and SSD temperatures.

Can you post the output of systemctl --reverse list-dependencies poweroff.target and systemctl --reverse list-dependencies shutdown.target?

Outputs in main body kos, thanks. Where would I find a log of temps? If I could tie a temperature back to the precise time this shutdown happened I guess that would be helpful, however I don't think high load/temps are causing these intermittent shutdowns.

To check on temperatures use lm-sensors: https://askubuntu.com/a/53782/380067 (by the way to reply to users you should use "@" followed by the username, otherwise they may not be notified of your comment mentioning them)

@kos Thanks here's the data

The core temperature is on the high side. My guess is when the CPU is under load, it overheats and shuts down. Is this a laptop or a desktop? If desktop, try to remove dust from inside. I had a similar problem with an Intel Skylake NUC.

If it's a laptop or a NUC, you may have to get it cleaned by a professional.

Now that I'm listening to it the fan is going pretty hard. I'm surprised you don't get an indication of thermal shutdown with the journalctl command? I'll open up the NUC and have a crack at cleaning it. Thanks for the help guys I really appreciate it.

The problem with the NUC is the CPU (and CPU fan) is at the bottom side of the motherboard. You have to take the motherboard out. Best of luck!

@user68186 Yeah I've had it open and cleaned it before but I didn't pull it from the adhesive pad and get to the underside and fan which is clearly where it needs the service. Thanks for the help I appreciate it :)
